# How to call window OnClick in sequence

Tags: javascript

My code here calls the 2 functions at the same time. How do I call in the first function first then followed by the second function?

```
window.onclick = myFunction;
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "∠CAD=∠DAE (AD bisects ∠CAE)";
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Select one of the statements to continue:";
  document.getElementById("button1").className = 'button1';
  document.getElementById("button2").className = 'button2';
}

window.onclick = myFunction2;
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Now let’s complete the proof! Select the next statement:";
        document.getElementById("button3").className = 'button3';
  document.getElementById("button4").className = 'button4';
}

 const handleClick = function() { myFunction(); myFunction2();};
    window.onclick = handleClick;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want, do you want, first click call first function, then on second click, call the the second function, or do you want to on click, call the first, and then the second when first is complete?

Comment: I want the first click call first function, then on second click, call the the second function

Answer (score 1):

Set the on click handler to be the first function, then have the first function redefine/reset the window's onclick function callback.

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "∠CAD=∠DAE (AD bisects ∠CAE)";
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Select one of the statements to continue:";
  document.getElementById("button1").className = 'button1';
  document.getElementById("button2").className = 'button2';

  // reset the onClick handler
  window.onclick = myFunction2;
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Now let’s complete the proof! Select the next statement:";
  document.getElementById("button3").className = 'button3';
  document.getElementById("button4").className = 'button4';
}

window.onclick = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put function2 in function1 as

```js
//window.onclick = myFunction; //remove this, because when myfunction trigger, then it call myFunction2 also
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "∠CAD=∠DAE (AD bisects ∠CAE)";
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Select one of the statements to continue:";
  document.getElementById("button1").className = 'button1';
  document.getElementById("button2").className = 'button2';
  
  myFunction2();  //just call from here;
}

//window.onclick = myFunction2; // no need to do this
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Now let’s complete the proof! Select the next statement:";
        document.getElementById("button3").className = 'button3';
  document.getElementById("button4").className = 'button4'; 
  
}

 const handleClick = function() { myFunction(); };
    window.onclick = handleClick;
```

Comment: When I click the window the second time, myFunction2() is not called.

Comment: for that you need to use a variable as a counter and then you just check that its second time, then call it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this code will run in the global window, so you may need a variable that stores the state whether you've clicked the first time or not

```js
var isFirstClicked = false;

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "∠CAD=∠DAE (AD bisects ∠CAE)";
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
    "Select one of the statements to continue:";
  document.getElementById("button1").className = "button1";
  document.getElementById("button2").className = "button2";
  isFirstClicked = true;
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML =
    "Now let’s complete the proof! Select the next statement:";
  document.getElementById("button3").className = "button3";
  document.getElementById("button4").className = "button4";
}

const handleClick = function() {
  if (!isFirstClicked) {
    myFunction();
  } else {
    myFunction2();
  }
};
window.onclick = handleClick;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="demo">Demo 1</div>
  <div id="demo2">Demo 2</div>
  <div id="demo4">Demo 4</div>
  <button type="button" id="button1">button1</button>
  <button type="button" id="button2">button2</button>
  <button type="button" id="button3">button3</button>
  <button type="button" id="button4">button4</button>
</body>

</html>
```